# Solving a second order ODE $ t^2 \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+t\frac{dy}{dt}-y=t $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a hard time solving this equation:

$$ t^2 \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+t\frac{dy}{dt}-y=t $$

I decided to look in the textbook  and the only question I saw that was somewhat similar was this:

$$ t^2 \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+t\frac{dy}{dt}+y=0 $$

However, the question was a non-homogeneous and the one in the book is homogeneous.

So I decided to tackle it:

What I did was divide by $t^2$ to get:

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{1}{t}\frac{dy}{dt}-\frac{y}{t^2}=\frac{1}{t} $$

and what I want to do next is minus $\frac{1}{t}$ but then I'm not sure what to really do even if I do minus. So if anyone want to provide a method, that would be lovely.

In addition, another question I have is can non-homogeneous equations be made into homogeneous equations? The reason I ask this is because if I do minus $\frac{1}{t}$ then the right hand side will be 0 which means this equation becomes homogeneous.

Comment: Can you use Laplace Transforms?

Comment: @graydad, no we did not learn that.

Comment: You can solve the homogeneous version and use the method of variation of parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Euler-Cauchy equation. You can try setting $t=e^x$. Then $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}e^x$, and some calculation will give you $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{2x}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$.

So the equation can be transformed into

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-y=e^x$$ Now you can use characteristic equation to find the solution of this differential equation and substitute back for $t$.

To answer your other question. No, when you subtract $1/t$, it does not make it homogeneous. It should contain only $y$ terms for it to be homogeneous. It doesn't matter whether the terms are on the left or right hand side.

Comment: hmm. I think im a bit confuse still but isn't the general form of a second order homogeneous differential eq: $a \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+b \frac{dy}{dt}+cy=0$, so I just want to clarify, what do you mean by it should not contain y terms?

Comment: I'm sorry. :) It should be just the opposite. The homogeneous equation contains only $y$ terms.

Answer (score 3):

An archaic solution could be: 
$$
t^2y''+ty'-y=\left(t^3\left(\frac{y}{t}\right)'\right)'.
$$
Therefore:
$$
\left(\frac{y}{t}\right)'=\frac{1}{2t}+\frac{c}{t^3},
$$
and
$$
y=\frac{t}{2}\ln\vert t\vert +\frac{a}{t}+bt.
$$